# How to define in composer.json to get zf2 library update?

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

i have kept the zf2 library inside vendor folder as follows . How to define composer to set zf2 updated through composer?
[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be managed by Composer, remove your existing vendor folder and have Composer set it up again. See the [ZF skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/composer.json) for an example of adding ZF2 to your composer.json.

Comment: This is fine . but is it possible to define our own structure as mentioned above?

Comment: You can specify installation paths for composer packages, see http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md - but sticking to the defaults will probably make your life easier in the long run.